# Asp.net problem while retrieving "confirm()" values in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wonder why the Java Script function is not returning the Confirm value properly.

I have this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveAgreement" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Save" OnClientClick ="ConfirmSaveWithoutSendEmail(this);" />
```

I have this Java Script function:

```
 function ConfirmSaveWithoutSendEmail(btnToDisableWhileSubmitting)
    {           
        var IsPanelToSendEmailVisible = document.getElementById('<%= hfIsSendEmailPanelVisible.ClientID%>').value; 

        if (IsPanelToSendEmailVisible > 0)
        {
            //This section takes a confirmation "Ok/Cancel" to submit or not 
            //the data, the problem is that if I choose "Cancel", the code 
            //on the button is executed, the behavior I would except is such 
            //that selecting "Cancel"  the code on my button is not 
            //executed.

            return confirm("Do you want to save without send email?");
        }
        else
        {                
            //this section disable the button while submitting information, 
            //this section works fine.

            if (!Page_ClientValidate())
                return false;

            btnToDisableWhileSubmitting.disabled = true;
            btnToDisableWhileSubmitting.value = 'Saving...';
            return true;
        }
      }
```

Why the confirm value selected always is taken as true?

I wonder what I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the code you set in the `OnClientClick` attribute isn't actually returning anything, it's just executing the `ConfirmSaveWithoutSendEmail` function but not actually using it's return value.  You should also set `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` so that it submits your form on click.  Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveAgreement" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return ConfirmSaveWithoutSendEmail(this);" />
```

The `else` part of your `if` statement will also not work, because you are disabling the button before it is able to submit the form.  You will need to disable the form in the `submit` event of the form:

```
document.getElementById('yourFormId')
    .addEventListener('submit', function() { 
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById('<%= btnSaveAgreement.ClientID %>');
        submitBtn.disabled = true;
        submitBtn.value = 'Saving...';
    });
```

Comment: I put "return ConfirmSaveWithoutSendEmail(this)"; but now nothing happens when taking the "Ok/Cancel" response, there is no submitted data on both cases, and the code that was working "disable the button while submitting information" is now not working, the button all the time keeps "Saving..." and never makes a submit after pressed.

Comment: you didn't provide your full html, but if you want the button submit a `<form>` then try setting `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` on your button in addition to my answer

Comment: I put UseSubmitBehavior="true" additionally to your answer. Now the section for taking the response "Ok/Cancel" is WORKING FINE, the second part of the section "disable the button while submitting information" has not the problem with the "Saving..." text any more, but the code behind inside the button  is never executed after pressing the button.

Comment: it's because you're disabling the button before the actual postback occurs, and a disabled button is not allowed to submit a form.  You would have to add an event listener to your form element to handle the `submit` event, and inside that function you'd disable the button.

Comment: @pepe I updated my answer with more information, did that solve your issue?